# Rules for dealing with email in mu4e

Tags: mu4e

The Mail application in macOS allows creation of rules, such as `Sender X and keyword Y in subject -> mark as read and move to archive.` I am looking for something similar in mu4e.

[Smart refiling](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Smart-refiling.html#Smart-refiling) has a similar feature:

> you can select some messages in the headers view, then press `r`, and have them all marked for refiling to their particular folders.

What I'm looking for is that result without having to see the message or press `r` to refile it.

Does it exist?

Comment: See [smart refiling](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Smart-refiling.html#Smart-refiling).

Comment: @jagrg Smart refiling still requires user input, I'd like the messages to be refiled without even seeing them. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. In any case, the function that does the refiling is called `mu4e~proc-move`, so all you need is the message's `docid` and target folder. But how do you know which messages are new during the indexing process? One way around this is to find messages flagged unread using the `mu find` command (see below).

```el
(defvar mu4e-find-new-messages-command
  "mu find maildir:/YOUR_INBOX_FOLDER flag:unread --format=sexp 2>/dev/null")

(defun mu4e-refile-messages ()
  (let* ((cmd mu4e-find-new-messages-command)
         (res (concat "(list" (shell-command-to-string cmd) ")"))
         (msgs (car (read-from-string res))))
    (unless (equal '(list) msgs)
      (dolist (msg msgs)
        (when-let ((docid (mu4e-message-field msg :docid))
                   (maildir (funcall mu4e-refile-folder msg)))
          (mu4e~proc-move docid maildir))))))

(add-to-list 'mu4e-index-updated-hook 'mu4e-refile-messages)
```

Comment: Is the logic that I would create smart refiling rules as in the manual, and your function and hook applies them each time the mu4e index is updated?

Comment: That's the logic, yes.

Comment: I finally got around to try this, sorry for the delay. I can't get it to work. I have a rule with a single condition on `mu4e-message-contact-field-matches msg :from "..."`, which I checked in the source code to be valid. This should refile after I run `M-x mu4e` and `U`, right?