# Mark all email in mu4e as read

Tags: mu4e

I have downloaded my emails using getmail and indexed them by mu. The problem now is that my mu4e has around 50000 emails that are marked as unread: is there a simply way to mark the entire Maildir as read?

I have tried a couple of scripts external to emacs adding the flag "S" to all the emails, then when I open mu4e they all still have unread flag.

Comment: To mark all messages in the *buffer* there's `mu4e-headers-mark-for-read`, so you could use `(while (not (eobp)) (mu4e-headers-mark-for-read))`. The problem is I can only get 500 messages to show at a time, so you might need several runs to finish.

Comment: FWIW, there is a toggle to show all instead of only the first 500 matches (at least in `mu4e 1.10.3` - in the mu4e view press `P` for the toggles, then `f` for full-search on/off).

Then your above would work with fewer iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `mu` itself doesn't let you interactuate with it in that way using predefined commands that I'm aware of. I guess that if you know enough about xapian databases, which isn't my case, you could do it. Still, you have a few options out of the box.

- On `mu4e-contrib` you have `mu4e-headers-mark-all-unread-read`, which probably will fit your bill for most use cases. Notice that only flag visible emails, but doesn't excute it, which means:

  1. you're more likely operating on a subset of your stored messages. How big the subset is depends on `mu4e-headers-results-limit`'s value, which by default is 500 IIRC.
  2. you still have to execute your actions.

  Mind you that almost always your day-to-day workflow will be operating on subsets defined by bookmarks. Thread messages, Today's messages, this month's messages, or whatever actual. Having unread messages outside of current/used scopes shouldn't mean much.
- Also, in `mu4e-contrib` you can find `mu4e-headers-mark-all` which asks what to do with the marks and execute. Still applies point 1.

If that falls short or lets you down the basics of doing a search and processing it are well described in [Rules for dealing with email in mu4e](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/55618/11477). It shouldn't be too hard to modify that code using the contributed functions cited above to make your own function. `mu script` is another option which will require a similar effort.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Mu script seemed like a good option, but I wasn't able to find any documentation for it.

Comment: Most of the pointers you'll ever find are here: https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu-guile.html